# Craft\WebApp and its behaviors do not have a method or closure named "getInfo"

Tags: error-message

Craft\WebApp and its behaviors do not have a method or closure named "getInfo".

appeared today, nothing has been updated or changed.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

Sounds like some of Craft's files are missing.  Try downloading the latest release from buildwithcraft.com and re-uploading the `craft/app` folder and see if that solves it.

**Update:**

Since the OP sent a ticket into support, I'll update that re-uploading the `craft/app` folder solved the problem.